# SQL - Multiple entries for foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is my first time here, don't know exactly how it goes. :)
I have a project at school for Databases, we use SQL in SQL Developer, with oracle express 11g. 
I chose to do a DB for a music festival and I have some problems with it. 
I'm having trouble populating the tables, I think it's mainly a design fault.

I have a table Music Festival which I wanted to use as a main table from which each table collapses into another one. What I don't understand is how I populate the tables for the ONE-TO-MANY relationships. 
From the MUSIC FESTIVAL table I have a ONE-TO-MANY relationship with the PUBLIC table which contains the info about every concert-goer. I put the TICKET_ID as a primary key in PUBLIC so I can use it as a Foreign Key in MUSIC_FESTIVAL, but when I got to insert the entries into the table I just got stuck.

Here it's the ERD to make it easier to understand:

[image]

And this is how it looks in SQL DEVELOPER:

[SQL DEVELOPER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJGY6.png)

This is the error I'm getting: 
*One error saving changes to table "ROBERT"."PUBLIC":
Row 1: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ROBERT.PUBLIC_MUSIC_FESTIVAL) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at line 1*

Also, I find it difficult to populate the tables because of those errors. SQL DEVELOPER doesn't let me enter the data on one table and after that go to another table to solve the errors.

Please help, I really need some.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Before you can add a public record, you have to add a music festival. Also, name isn't a good PK for a music festival...how many Lollapaloozas were there in...1993? You probably want a surrogate key like an integer for the PKs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The Music_festival table is sort of a dummy, i don't know how to call it. I don't really want to add more festivals to it, just one, it would be wonderful to add more, but it's not a must. The music_festival table has 3 columns which should gather entries from other tables(fest_stages from the STAGES table, fest_tickets from PUBLIC and VIP tables and fest_transportation which is the CAR_ID in the TRANSPORT table). How do I add those values to the table since I don't have the information in the other tables? it's very confusing to me :(

Comment: If you disable all of your fk constraints, you can add the data in any order you want... but if you break any of your rules, you won't be able to enable them later

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb you need to insert data in order. That is, insert into the parent first, then into the children table(s). Well... unless you are using deferrable constraints, but that's a fairly advanced subject you should avoid for now.

For example:

```
insert into MUSIC FESTIVAL (name, location, date, stages, tickets, transportation)
  values ('Monster', 'Tokio', date '2019-03-15', 12345678, 12);

insert into PUBLIC (public_name, ..., ticket_id, ...)
            values ('Abc', ...,       'Monster', ...);
```

The second insert, on the child table, includes the foreign key `Monster` already created by the first insert.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it easier to add entries into the tables by using sql code, than using the tool from SQL Developer? I only tried to add data by selecting the table in the tree and opening the "DATA" tab. Would it work this way?

Comment: In real world development, you usually write all the SQL statements in scripts (.sql), that get stored into the source code repository. That way all the developers of the project can retrieve them, patch them, and improve them. At first it's easy to use GUIs, like the one you are trying, but after some time you rarely use nice looking GUIs to manage databases. SQL scripts also give you traceability, so you can find out who and when modified critical data.

Comment: I understand. I will try to add the data this way, hope it works. Using the GUI was a lot easier because of all the data I have to enter. Thanks!

Comment: If you save the file. you can run it multiple times, until is clean/high quality. Just re-create the [empty] database, and fire up the script.

Comment: Most data goes into the DB via your application, not SQL scripts.. there's nothing wrong with using a GUI but you should be comfortable with writing SQL by hand as well